# GNOME Sushi freezes system when previewing OpenDocument in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, previews, odt, gnome-sushi

I installed Sushi to be able to preview files. However, when I try to preview OpenDocument files, the entire system freezes. Why do OpenDocument files do this, and are there any alternatives that do not have this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Installing the **unoconv converter** solved the issue for me and other users

```
sudo apt install unoconv
```

This package provides a commandline utility which can convert from any document format that LibreOffice can import to any document format it can export. It uses LibreOffice's UNO bindings for non-interactive conversion of documents.

Supported document formats include Open Document format, LibreOffice Writter, MS Word, MS Office Open/MS OOXML, PDF, HTML, XHTML, RTF, DocBook, ODT, ODS, XLS and more.

[Original Solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-sushi/+bug/1739893)